# Probability of 20 students reach a cumulative total of 64 distinct names out of 254

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

There are 20 students in a class. The professor asked each of them to write down 10 different counties of Texas in their notebook. None of the students know what other students are picking. Assuming that all the 20 students wrote down the name of 10 different counties each and that too randomly, then what is the probability that at least 25% of the counties of Texas had appeared. There are 254 counties in Texas.

Comment: Why does [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3827491/what-is-the-probability-that-at-least-25-of-the-counties-had-a-chart-turned-in) keep appearing?   Is it on some take home exam or the like?

Comment: I got this question in a common Facebook group mostly formed by amateurs who love Mathematics. I would be very grateful if you could please advise me on how to proceed.

Comment: This is what I eventually did to solve this problem. Could anyone please confirm my work posted as my answer.

Comment: There are so many copies of the same question. Is all of it from the same facebook group posting this question? See for example -  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3827491/what-is-the-probability-that-at-least-25-of-the-counties-had-a-chart-turned-in

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a way to solve this, although the conclusion is that the probability of at least 25% of the counties appearing is a practical
certainty: it is 1 − 9.47965*(10^−23).

I will use the indicator variable method. For each county n, we let I(n) be a random variable that is 0 if the county is NOT chosen and 1 if it is chosen. For I(n) to be 0, none of the students must choose county
n. The probability of one student not choosing county n is
(253/254)*(252/253)* ... *(244/245) = 244/254
and the probability of none of the 20 students choosing it is = (244/254)^(20).

Let's write μ for the mean of I(n) (all I(n)
have the same mean), which is the same as the probability that I(n) = 1, so

μ = 1 − (244/254)^20 ≈ 0.552161

The sum of all 254 I(n)'s is a random variable with the binomial distribution, n = 254, p = μ, and we can figure from the binomial distribution what the probabilities are (or more simply approximate it
with a normal distribution).
The mean is 254*μ ≈ 140.249 with standard deviation ≈ 7.92521.

[I checked this out with a simulation of the 20 students randomly picking 10 distinct counties each out of 254.
After running the test 1 million times, the observed mean was 140.253, very close to the prediction, so I'm confident that the model is correct. In this simulation the smallest number of counties that
appeared in a trial was 116, much more that 64.]

Comment: All I(n) will not have the same mean. You can choose any county to start from but that restricts possibilities for next set of counties to appear as each student can get only $10$ counties. The appearance of a county is not completely independent of other counties appearance. Also on your method, it depends on whether the question seeks an answer that you are providing. If I toss a fair coin $10$ times, it is "practically" certain that I would get at least one head but it is still a valid question to ask what is the probability that you would get at least one head in $10$ tosses.